# Conditional subsetting by group

Tags: r

Example data:

```
mydf<-data.frame(Group_ID=c("337", "337", "201", "201", "470", "470", "999", "999"), 
                              Timestamp=c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), 
                              MU=as.numeric(c("1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "4", "5", "6")))
```

Gives:

```
    Group_ID Timestamp MU
         337         A  1
         337         A  1
         201         B  2
         201         B  3
         470         C  4
         470         D  4
         999         E  5
         999         F  6
```

Where MU is greater than 1, I would like to only retain the first entry within Group_ID. Where MU is <= 1, I would like to keep all entries for that group. Thus,

Desired result:

```
    Group_ID Timestamp MU
         337         A  1
         337         A  1
         201         B  2
         470         C  4
         999         E  5
```

I've made many attempts, the closest being the example below. However, this solution is wrong because it excludes all entries where MU <= 1.

Best attempt:

```
mydf <- mydf[(mydf$MU >= 1),] %>%            
  group_by(Group_ID) %>% 
  slice(1:1)
```

Returns undesired result (all MU <= 1 excluded rather than retained):

```
Group_ID Timestamp    MU
     201         B     2
     337         A     1
     470         C     4
     999         E     5
```

I'm surprised this attempt doesn't work, what's it missing? I've also tried `ifelse` statements. Many thanks in advance

Comment: Which rows should be kept in a group with `MU` values of `c(2, 3, 1, 1, 4)`?

Comment: what about `subset(mydf,ave(MU<2,Group_ID,FUN = function(x)x|(seq_along(x)<2)))` in base R?

Answer (score 5):

```
mydf %>%
    group_by(Group_ID) %>%
    filter(cumsum(MU > 1) <= 1) %>%
    ungroup()
## A tibble: 5 x 3
#  Group_ID Timestamp    MU
#  <fct>    <fct>     <dbl>
#1 337      A             1
#2 337      A             1
#3 201      B             2
#4 470      C             4
#5 999      E             5
```

Base R equivalent would be

```
mydf[with(mydf, ave(MU > 1, Group_ID, FUN = cumsum) <= 1),]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `which` within slice to select the desired row indices.

edit: not clear to me what to do when there are rows with MU <= 1 and rows with MU > 1 in the same group. This answer keeps the MU <= 1 rows for that group and the first MU > 1 row.

```
mydf %>% 
  group_by(Group_ID) %>% 
  slice(c(which(MU <= 1), head(which(MU > 1), 1)))

# # A tibble: 5 x 3
# # Groups:   Group_ID [4]
#   Group_ID Timestamp    MU
#   <fct>    <fct>     <dbl>
# 1 201      B             2
# 2 337      A             1
# 3 337      A             1
# 4 470      C             4
# 5 999      E             5
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do a group by 'Group_ID' and `slice` based on whether there are `any` element in 'MU' greater than 1

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% 
  group_by(Group_ID = factor(Group_ID, levels = unique(Group_ID))) %>%
  slice(if(any(MU> 1)) 1 else row_number() )
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   Group_ID [4]
#  Group_ID Timestamp    MU
#  <fct>    <fct>     <dbl>
#1 337      A             1
#2 337      A             1
#3 201      B             2
#4 470      C             4
#5 999      E             5
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. It adds a couple lines, so it's not quite as concise, but it's still quick and easy.

```
mydf1 <- mydf[(mydf$MU > 1),] %>%            
    group_by(Group_ID) %>% 
    slice(1:1)  
mydf2 <- rbind(mydf[(mydf$MU <= 1),],as.data.frame(mydf1))
mydf2
```